# Change border line colors when unfocused (react-native-paper)

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-paper

I have a textinput that changes color if the conditions are met or not (green to brown and vice versa) when it is focused.

I would like the colors to stay the same even when the input is unfocused.

Focused and verifications not ok:

[image: Focused and verifications not ok]

Focused and verifications ok:

[image: Focused and verifications ok]

Unfocused verifications okay or not:

[image: Unfocused verifications okay or not]

My code:

```
//Change brow to green, green to brown
const [inputColor, setInputColor] = useState("brown");

<TextInput
  //{...}
  theme={{
    colors: {
      primary: inputColor,
      underlineColor: inputColor,
    },
  }}
/>;
```

I tried to change:

- underlineColor props.
- borderColor, backgroundColor, color in styles, but nothing is working so far.

Answer (score 0):

try underlineColor
Type: string
Inactive underline color of the input.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to change the placeholder color `theme={{ colors: { primary: 'blue', placeholder: 'blue', }, }}`